# File in the asked folder

Tags: java, directory

I'm trying to make a small program that allows to create a 'txt' file. My teacher taught me to use BufferedReader and PrintWriter but I don't know how to allow the user to choose the path (you know, like when you save something on a software).

Thanx for your answer. 
(Sorry for my english, not my native language)

Comment: what kind of small program? Do you have UI?

Comment: This is not homework... I'm working for real (in an enterprise), but I'm at my second year as a student so I have some difficults to things I've never seen before. I tried to search but didn't find how to do what I mean. I don't ask to be judged, juste some help. I don't ask the whole code.

Comment: I'd like an interface. With the console, I know how to do it, but not with an interface. This is for an ordinary user

Comment: Maybe what you want is a [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), which pops up a dialog box the allows the user to choose a file or folder.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes, I think this is it, but I didn't completely understood how to use it. (Sorry, this is the first time I ask something on coding, so I don't have the habits :x) 
Moreover, what's the difference between Jfilechooser and filechooser ?

Comment: `JFileChooser` and `FileChooser` are basically the same thing, just from different GUI toolkits.  `JFileChooser` is from Swing, `FileChooser` is from JavaFX.  I suggested `JFileChooser` because I happen to be a Swing developer, but either one would probably do the job for you.

Comment: Okay, thanx a lot, I'll read more on it. Hope my question will help another one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can input it with a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and then append the file name to it using [`Path#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-):

```
System.out.println("Please enter the target directory: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String dir = in.next();
String filePath = Paths.get(dir, "myfile.txt").toString();

// Go on and create the file as you would normally do
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answer.
But, isn't it with a console ?

Comment: @VénianeLAM yup, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I'm looking for how to ask the path to the user, but with an interface. Sorry for not having been more specific in my question :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use BufferedReader and it is console app.

```
public class CreateFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));) {
            System.out.println("Enter the path");
            String path = br.readLine();
            File file = new File(path);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("File is created!");
            }

        }
    }
```

**Output**

Enter the path

./file/test.txt

File is created!

with interface, for simplest way to get user input

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CreateFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String path = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the path");
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("File is created!");
        }
    }

}
```

here is [Java Swing – JOptionPane showInputDialog example](https://www.mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-joptionpane-showinputdialog-example/)

Comment: Thanx for your answer !